# Block advertising from appearing on YouTube channels

Tags: youtube, ads

A customer of mine has created a YouTube channel for their business but is concerned about the advertising distracting from the product.

Is there any way to stop or prevent the adverts from appearing?

The channel is here - http://www.youtube.com/user/AtholeStillOpera

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there currently is no way to do this server-side i.e. clients will have to install some form of *AdBlocking* technology for their respective browsers, but at least there are *many* options available e.g. *Ad Block Plus*.

The fact of the matter is, Google sadly still has yet to offer some type of *pay option* to disable ads - both for *viewers* and *directors*!

Due to this reason, several friends have moved over to **Vimeo** and **MetaCafe** which (currently still) never displays *directly on videos*, instead opting for ads displaying only on the side of the page. I'm not sure about MetaCafe but Vimeo also lets you embed videos in your website e.g. Wordpress blogs - where you will never see an advertisement!

Comment: I use Ad Block Plus and it blocks most of them !

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you *can* block advertisements from appearing on Youtube channels.**

This **only** works on videos that the user has uploaded. I looked at the channel in the original post, which has approximately 70 nice music videos, all were uploaded. In the Youtube settings panel for the channel, you have the option of disabling ads on all videos that you uploaded. It can't be done on an individual basis; it is all or nothing. This option has been there for awhile, even prior to the changes to Youtube that Google did recently, but it was in a different (easier to find, for me) place before. It may have been directly in AdSense or AdWords, I don't recall now.

Note that it is **NOT** possible to disable advertising for videos that you did not upload though, not as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is not the same question, as it is asked from the user's point of view (client side, not server side, I guess is the right way that I should phrase that). The answers might be helpful, as they suggest some alternatives to AdBlock, and are current http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18453/how-can-i-disable-the-advertisements-shown-before-youtube-videos