# Is there any software or way to disable ads in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block advertising from appearing on YouTube channels](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/block-advertising-from-appearing-on-youtube-channels)

I watch a lot of subtitled videos so it's hard to follow along when ads block the subtitles every minute.

IE 8.  Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

An ad-blocking HOSTS file like the MVPS one will do the trick. (It'll block ad servers for every app on your system and I can personally confirm that the MVPS one does kill whatever servers YouTube pulls ads from)

http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm

They've got simplified instructions for Windows 7 at the top of this page:

http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hostswin7.htm

You only need a few lines from it, but since it's not trivial to figure out which ad servers a Flash applet is contacting, my advice is to just follow their instructions and block all ad servers.

Comment: Wow, how do I go about making it work for YT?  I find that link overwhelming.  What few lines do you mean?  Can you babywalk me?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some clarifications including a link that uses screenshots to walk you through the install process.

Comment: It looks like I have to mess with the registry.  Too risky especially since System Restore is not working properly.  Thank you but it's a tinge too complex for me.  So, there's no simpler way, eh? Software, that does this task?

Comment: Everything below "Editing the HOSTS file" is optional. The two screenshots and the text between and above them are all you need. (Obviously, the guys who run that site aren't web design guys)